# How to Change the Language in Alert view using NSLocalizedString

Tags: swift, nslocalizedstring

When I am using in this line

```
alertView.message=NSLocalizedString("Please_enter_all_fields",comment:"Please_enter_all_fields")
```

alert pop up messages shows `Please_enter_all_fields`, but I was declared the `Localized.string` file: `Please_enter_all_fields="Please enter all fields"`.
How can I display the alert message related declared String of `Localized.string` variables?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, have a look at the formatting changes I've made to your post. You can use such formatting both in posts and comments. See "help" right under the "Add Comment" button. Your usage of parentheses is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

may be this is wrong

> Please_enter_all_fields="Please enter all fields"

It's must be setting like below:

> "Please_enter_all_fields"="Please enter all fields";

Comment: Hai Jay Choi, Thank you for your response. if i am using ("Please_enter_all_fields"="Please enter all fields";) in this line same output is displayed.

Comment: have you insert in Localized.string to () characters?

Comment: Yes, i am inserting in Localized.string to () characters.but I am getting the same output

Comment: Oh, no, format for Localized strings must be like this: "key"="value"; not need some brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
let title = NSLocalizedString("TITLE", comment: "TITLE") 
let msg = NSLocalizedString("Please_enter_all_fields", comment: "Please_enter_all_fields")

let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
```

The NSLocalizedString is default as "English - Development Language".

you can just define the value as you want

```
let msg = NSLocalizedString("Please enter all fields", comment: "Please enter all fields")
```

[image]

Or you have to add "English" Localisations, and translate inside "Localizable.String(English(United States))"

[image]

```
/* Please_enter_all_fields */
"Please_enter_all_fields" = "Please enter all fields";
```